# How to make Eclipse's tab's background color changed when use dark theme?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

I am trying to make my Eclipse cooler like IntelliJ's darcular theme.  Everything is fine now except the tab's background's color. It's white and I can't see the words clearly.
Just like the picture below.
[image]

Oh, I don't know why it can be seen in the screenshot.
But what I want like this:
[image]

Comment: What version are you running? It [looks ok for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fS7X5.png) on *Luna (4.4.0)*, I just changed to Theme to Dark.

Comment: Take a look at "General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts > View and Editor Folders": "Active, selected part background begin" seems to control that blue-gray light shade for me.

Answer (score 3):

By [TWiStErRob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/253468/twisterrob)'s comment I found where to change it for me, which also had bright tabs when switching to dark theme.

Below the steps how I changed my tabs:

Go in the top menu to window, then preferences.

[image: window > preferences]

Then drill down to **General > Appearance > colors and fonts**
There is a list with **multiple** background begin, background end options. If you select an option you can use the edit button to change the color.

[image: How to change tab colors]

Default you only get the basic colors. By clicking the *Define Custom Colors >>** button you can use a color picker or the hex/hsl editor fields to enter your own preferred colors. I changed them all *(all the background begin/background end options)* from their bright colors to darker colors.

[image: color picker]

The end result.

[image: end result]

Thanks to [TWiStErRob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/253468/twisterrob) for giving the pointer where to find the setting.